# The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget

So, I have a MVC 4 project in C# and I am using Visual Studio For Web 2012 Express.

I cannot compile the projecto due to the error:
The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Normally, this would mean that a library is missing. Thus after making a quick search on the internet I used NuGet to install `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`, but that still did not work.

What makes this intriguing to me is that BundleCollections should be known to the application by deafult. I can only imagine that I have added a dependency that messed everything up, but I really can't know for sure.

How can I fix this problem? What am I missing here?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Dockis
{

    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            IItemTransform cssFixer = new CssRewriteUrlTransform();

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

           //...
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT

After checking my references folder I tried running the command `Install-Package System.Web.Optimization`, however I cannot install this package. I get the following error:

```
Install-Package : One or more errors occurred.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  System.Web.Optimization
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What is odd, is the fact that running `Install-Package System.Web.Optimization.Less` works, and fixes some depencie problems, but **not** all of them. Thus I believe I really need the first command to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `System.Web.Optimization` listed under the References folder in your project?

Comment: I updated the question with more details. I do not have that file in my references folder, and after trying to install it I fail miserably, but I don't know why :S

Comment: I'd be tempted to see if the Nuget Package Manager extension has an update.

Comment: I have updated all the packages, but I still can't install System.Web.Optimization. Aparently Nuget cannot find it, only finds System.Web.Optimization.Less.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no clear answer for this question. 
I managed to fix the project only by re-creating it, and then downloading all the DLLs in a different order, closing and re-opening the visual studio several times while doing it.

Aparently there was some conflict between some  of the packages, but that was impossible to guess until I had re-created the project from scratch again.

Running `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` did solve the problem after the clean install  however, so I recommend it.

I thank everyone for the help.

Comment: This answer is basically outdated now due to more changes with nuget, MVC5 packages and all kinds of unknowns. Thx for nothing microsoft.

Comment: The answer is just barely off. The package to reinstall is named 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization'.

Comment: I am real close to ramming my keyboard through my computer screen right now.  I can't take it anymore.

Comment: Thanks, running Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization resolved it for me .net 4.7.2 and MVC 5.7.2, Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.0.0

Comment: Worked for me.   1) remove package 2) add package 3) Clean 4) restart VS 5) rebuild.   
 Flame is correct and that you must restart VS.  +1

Answer (score 8):

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Answer (score 3):

Install Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization on the NuGet Package Manager. If it's already installed but not working try install a previous version and then the last version again. Worked for me, :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just an addition to the solutions already identified for this issue. In my case, none of the above solutions worked. In the end, I had to manually locate the DLL in my .NET folders on my local drive and add the System.Web.Optimization.dll to my project manually.

Visual Studio 2017 indicated sucessful installation of the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3 package, however, did not allow the DLL to be added to the project. So even though the Nuget install was successful, the app would not compile. **Manually adding the DLL to the project fixed it.**

Answer (score 1):

For broken projects:

- Right-click on `References -> Manage NuGet Packages`
- Find `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` in the `browse` section
- Downgrade it to the previous version
- If everything is ok, then roll it back to the latest version

Should work for such kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was fixed by closing Visual Studio, deleting the `.vs` and `packages` folders. Then I started Visual Studio again and ran `Update-Package -reinstall` in the `Package Manager Console` and finally installed `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`.